# Can't RedirectToAction with Parameter when using MapControllerRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

While having this route mapping:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    "ViewAct",
    "Cont1/Act1/{id}/{title?}",
    new { controller = "Cont1", action = "Act", id = "" });
```

When calling `RedirectToAction` from a different controller action, the id parameter will arrive as zero `0`;

So when calling redirect from here:

```
public ActionResult Act2(long id, long nid) // id = 123
{    
    return RedirectToAction("Act1", new { id = id, title = "" });
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Act1(long id, string title) // id == 0
```

`id` will be `0`.

Redirecting from Act1 to Act1 works (`id` gets value), also if I delete the `MapControllerRoute` on top, it will also work.

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @Jackdaw calling `return RedirectToAction("Act1", new { id, title = realTitle });`  from `Act1` code works, the `id` gets value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `id` value from the defaults parameter:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    "ViewAct",
    "Home/Act1/{id}/{title?}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Act1"});
```

Providing the valid default value (which can be parsed into `long`) for `id` also works:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    "ViewAct",
    "Home/Act1/{id}/{title?}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Act1", id = "0" });
```

Comment: thnx, it worked, no idea why that `id` value was causing this

Comment: @buga wasg glad to help! It seams that caveat was that empty string is not a valid value in this context so it resulted in some problems when building redirect link.